# preg_match a String to get certain numbers out of the string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that always has the following format

`Text: 1.1111111 Text`

What I need is `1.11` of the string

So I went with this regex

`^(\S*\s)(\d.\d{2})`

I've used http://regex101.com/ to try it out and it works there, but when I do it on my own code, the matches array is always empty.

This is the code

```
//$ratingString = Durchschnittsbewertung: 4.65000 von 5 Sternen 20 Bewertungen Location bewerten 
preg_match ( "/^(\S*\s)(\d.\d{2})/", $ratingString, $matches );
var_dump ( $matches );
// matches == array (0) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the dot as dot is special character in regex which matches **any character if not escaped**:

```
^(\S*\s)(\d\.\d{2})
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I edited it, to `preg_match ( "/^(\S*\s)(\d\.\d{2})/", $ratingString, $matches );` but it's still empty. Is there any other character I have to escape?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. The problem was, that there were **2** whitespaces in the sourcecode, even though the string showed only one, so now I made it `\s+` instead of just `\s` but I will still accept your answer as the correct one. :) Thank

Answer (score 2):

god, so here...sorry for editing. like this

```
$ratingString = "Durchschnittsbewertung: 4.65000 von 5 Sternen 20 Bewertungen Location bewerten";
preg_match ( "#(\d\.\d{2})#", $ratingString, $matches );
var_dump ( $matches );
```

Comment: I voted your answer up, since it also works with less code. But why do you have the `#` at the start and the `#sU` at the end?

Comment: ``#`` is my personal fav delimter for handling with regex and the mod ``U`` is pointless - ur right thanks. is it bad to use ``#`` ?

Comment: `#` seems like a good delimiter to me, I think I've written 1 regex ever that had to match a `#`, whereas I've written many that had to match `/`. @Musterknabe you can use pretty much any symbol as a delimiter, you then have to escape that symbol if you want to match it in the regex, e.g. to match `n/a` you could use `/n\/a/` (escaping the literal `/`), or you could use `@n/a@`.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know that you can have any delimiter you want to. Thanks!